# Aix Visual Age C++ moved from version 8 to version 11 template issue

Tags: c++, aix

The problem we are experiencing is calling a method in a class encapsulated in a template.

```
void BuildData(DataBuilder &dBuild, char* name="AccountDetails") { ... }
```

In the version 8 compiler invoking this method with a single parameter picks up the default value and works.

In the version 11 compiler invoking this method with a single parameter we get a compilation error requiring we supply the second parameter explicitly therefore ignoring the default value.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-qnoro` or `-qro`?

Comment: What does this have to do with templates? And, yes, as MSalters said, for the default parameter to work a `const char[]` has to be converted into `char*`. I know there is a _deprecated_ conversion doing this when you request it explicitly. I'm not sure whether this extends to implicit such conversions.

Comment: I am quite happy that it maybe should be 'const char * name = "xxx"' and maybe I will consider the larger change to make it so.

Comment: Well we tested the const theory and that did not work at all. So we have to assume it is not const, but something with template usage in the version 11 compiler.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball didn't tell me there's a template involved. Maybe you could show us the relevant parts?

Comment: class DTaskDataDef { ...

Comment: I have mentioned template right from the beginning. It is a horrible usage of templates but I am not allowed to shoot the programmer who originally coded this. It is a mix of macros and templates and I do not wish to show all the offending code. Making the default parameter definition into an extra overloaded function rather solves the dilemma. I suspect the version 11 compiler is trying to improve the compile speed of templates and has introduced a gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide one argument, the default value `"AccountDetails"` has to be converted to type `char*`. Without seeing the error, I'm assuming that it's a "lost `const` qualifier"or whatever AIX calls that. A string literal may not be modified, but `name` points to a string that can be modified. Usually this is a warning, but this depends on the compiler setting.

The fix is probably to add the missing `const`.

Comment: We would like to know what changed from 8 to 11 to cause this to stop working. The code is generated and the obvious fix is to use overloaded functions rather than default parameters, but that does not allow for where we may have used it in a similar way.

Comment: ".../projects/valkyrie/code/c/libti/libs/libutil/anyidlplug/statictable.h", line 378.34: 1540-0215 (S) The wrong number of arguments has been sp ecified for "DTaskDataDef::BuildData(DataBuilder &, char *)".

Comment: It is very definitely influenced by the templates - The method is used all over the place outside any template code and it does not have a "const" problem straight code.